# gcc memory overlap between global variables and class members

Tags: gcc, memory-leaks, g++

I've been finally able to add the portion of code to explain my question ...

I've recently upgraded my development PC and with it gcc from 4.1 to 4.8.
Compiling the same source I'm experiencing now a var overlap issue.
I can't post the entire cource since it is huge but just for understand I have some variables defined before the main() that are defined as extern on outside class so that can be accessed.
Someone of theese global variables change their value unexpectedly and debugging this with gdb I can see that this variable is sharing the same memory address as one member of a class instance.

This is the definition of variables on main.cpp the variable loopcounter is the only one I really need, I've surrounded it with unused variables in order to better understand this overlap.

```
uint64_t loopcounterx = 0;
uint64_t loopcounterxx = 0;
uint64_t loopcounterxxx = 0;
uint64_t loopcounterxxxx = 0;
uint64_t loopcounterxxxxx = 0;
uint64_t loopcounterxxxxxx = 0;
uint64_t loopcounter = 0;
uint64_t loopcountery = 0;
uint64_t loopcounteryy = 0;
uint64_t loopcounteryyy = 0;
uint64_t loopcounteryyyy = 0;
uint64_t loopcounteryyyyy = 0;
uint64_t loopcounteryyyyyy = 0;
uint64_t loopcounteryyyyyyy = 0;

.
.
.

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

I've set a watchdog for this variable write access with gdb

```
watch loopcounter
```

when the program execution stops I can see that we are inside an instance of the class Timer

```
Hardware watchpoint 1: loopcounter

Old value = 541
New value = 66077


Timer::signal (this=0xc235b0 (loopcounteryyy), s=true) at chrono.cpp:229
```

this is the portion of chrono.cpp

```
bool Timer::signal (bool s) {
    if ((s != in_signal_old) && !r_pulse) {
        in_signal = s;
        if (s) in_signal_fp=true;
        else in_signal_rp=true;
        in_signal_old = s;
    }
}
```

the watchdog stops the execution at line 229 of chrono.cpp which contains

```
if (s) in_signal_fp=true;
```

at the time of stop, the memory violation has already happened, so I think we must consider the line before, that is

```
in_signal = s;
```

where the code is accessing a member of it's class and it really seems that the writeing of this member will damage the content of loopcounter variable.
In fact, looking to pointers I get this

```
(gdb) p &loopcounter
$1 = (uint64_t *) 0xc235c8 (loopcounter) 

(gdb) p &in_signal
$2 = (uint64_t *) 0xc235ca (loopcounter + 2)

(gdb) p &in_signal_fp
$5 = (bool *) 0xc235cc (loopcounter+4)

(gdb) p &active_f
$7 = (bool *) 0xc235c8 (loopcounter)
```

active_f is another member of the chrono class and it is perfectly overlapping the loopcounter variable.

this is the Timer class contained in chrono.h header

```
class Timer {
    private:
        Timer *me;
        Timer *prev;
        Timer *next;
        bool active_f;
        bool running_f;
        bool in_signal;
        bool in_signal_old;
        bool in_signal_fp;
        bool in_signal_rp;
        bool out_signal;
        bool out_signal_old;
        bool out_signal_fp;
        bool out_signal_rp;
        bool f_pulse;
        bool r_pulse;
        uint64_t start;
        uint64_t end;
        uint64_t lenght;
        timer_type type;
    public:
        int init (int lenght);
        bool out (void);
        bool active () { return active_f; }
        bool fp () { return f_pulse; }
        bool rp () { return r_pulse; }
        bool running () { return running_f; }
        void set_next (Timer *n) { next = n; }
        void set_prev (Timer *p) { prev = p; }
        void set_end (RTIME x) { end = x; }
        void set_active (bool x) { active_f = x; }
        void set_running (bool x) { running_f = x; }
        void set_lenght (RTIME x) { lenght = x; }
        void set_start (RTIME x) { start = x; }
        void set_type (timer_type x) { type = x; }
        void set_timer (RTIME x, timer_type y);// { lenght = x; type = y; }
        bool signal (bool);
        void set_fp (bool x) { f_pulse = x; }
        void set_rp (bool x) { r_pulse = x; }
        Timer * get_next () { return next; }
        Timer * get_prev () { return prev; }
        RTIME get_end () { return end; }
        RTIME get_start () { return start; }
        RTIME get_lenght (void) { return lenght; }
        void append (Timer *newt);
        Timer();
};
```

Why the compiler/linker or I don't know who else, is allocating two different objects on the same memory area ?

I've also used valgrind and the `-fsanitize=address` option introduced in gcc-4.8 but I can't get more useful informations or something more where to work on.

In which other way can I investigate over this behaviour ?

Comment: Can you add the code where you create the instance of the Timer class?

Comment: Object of  `Timer` class wasn't created correctly but we need more details to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Hi yugr, this is a 2 years old post, but thanks anyway for your interest.
Just to close it, at the end I've solved, and resulted to be a no compiler fault.
The mistake was a #ifdef condition inside a .h file.
The condition is passed to the compiler trought a -D option and the mistake is that the -D option was specified only on the compilation line of this source and not for the main that uses this source.
In this way, there is an address mismatch anche the memory leak I've described.